# How to remove right side elements of a string with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new to regex and python.

My patterns are

```
'Contact: Order Procesing'
'Contact: ice.cream@cream.com'
'Contact: Opr & Packaging Supply'
'Contact: JOE (continued)'
'Contact: BOB/LORA/JACKIE'
'Contact: Ben - FTTC CER (continued)'
```

now I need to find the pattern to match contact and remove the entire string with a blank space.

```
re.findall(r"Contact:",text)
```

matches text with Contact. The problem is I do not know how to remove the Contact and right part of the Contact.

Is there any most efficient pythonic way to do this

Comment: `print(re.sub(r"^Contact:.*", "", str))`?

Comment: you can also do `str.replace("Contact: ","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

d = ['Contact: Order Procesing', 'Contact: ice.cream@cream.com', 'Contact: Opr & Packaging Supply', 'Contact: JOE (continued)', 'Contact: BOB/LORA/JACKIE', 'Contact: Ben - FTTC CER (continued)']

for i in d:
    print(re.sub(r"^Contact:.*", "", i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all strings of your list started with the substring 'Contact: ', use this code:

```
new_list = [string[10:] for string in old_list]
```